# Response not getting rendered in Express js application

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple express application with the app.js code as shown below:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"
var packageJson = require("../package.json")
var path = require("path")
var express = require("express")
var csurf = require("csurf")
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

console.log("Loading App in "+env +" mode")

global.App={
app  : express(),
port : process.env.PORT || 3000,
version : packageJson.version,
name : packageJson.name,
mailSender : process.env.MAIL_SENDER || '"SchoolManagement"<no-reply@schoolManagement.com>',
root : path.join(__dirname,'..'),
urls : {
    root: process.env.ROOT_URL
        },
appPath : function(path){
    return this.root+'/'+path
},
require : function(path){
    return require(this.appPath(path))
},
env : env,
start : function (path) {
    if(!this.started){
        this.started=true
        this.app.listen(this.port)
        console.log("Running App Version: "+this.version+" On "+this.env+" On port: "+this.port)
    }
},
model: function(path){
    return this.require("app/models/"+path)
},
util : function(path){
    return this.require("app/utils/"+path)
},
route : function(path){
    return this.require("app/routes/"+path)
}
}
App.app.set('views','../views');
App.app.set('view engine','jade');
App.app.set('view options', {
layout: false
});
App.app.use(bodyParser.json)
App.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
App.app.use(require('method-override'))
App.app.use(require('cookie-parser'))
App.app.use(express.Router())
App.app.use(cookieSession({secret: "it'sasecrettoeverybody", key: "session"}))
App.app.use(express.static(App.appPath('public')))
App.require("config/routes")(App.app)

App.require('config/database')(process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/nodeslash_' + App.env)
```

And my routes.js is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(app){
var homeRoutes = App.route("homeRoutes")
app.get('/',homeRoutes.home)

var usersRoutes = App.route("userRoutes")
app.get("/sign_up",usersRoutes.new)
app.post("/sign_up",usersRoutes.create)

var sessionRoutes = App.route("sessionsRoutes")
app.get("/sign_in",sessionRoutes.new)
app.post("/sign_in",sessionRoutes.create)

}
```

But when i run the server.js file and open localhost:3000 on my browser,
the request is getting stuck with waiting for localhost:3000 and i am not getting any response, i have the proper mapping for the '/' get request as well, below is the request mapping:

```
exports.home = function(req,res){
res.render('home/home',{})
 }
```

I have the jade file as well in 'home' directory, its content is as follows:

```
extends ../layouts/home

block content
h1 Web's Premiere Browser Game

h2 Message from Borgoroth
```

I am new to node.js and jade, i am not able to get what is going wrong, i dont see any logs in console as well, can someone please help.

Comment: I don't see where you're including the routes file

Comment: App.require("config/routes")(App.app)

Comment: I can't see the error mostly because your code seems to be unbelieveably complicated for what it is. However, usually with express. When you get this kind of error where the page never seems to finish loading. It is usually because you are not handling the response correctly, so instead of returning something, it just does nothing. I'd check first if homeRoutes.home is actually being called by putting f.x. console.log('test') inside the function. And work my way from there. If you dont see "test" in the console. You know the function is never called.